# Disable Liveview timeout

Tags: canon, live-view, display, canon-1100d

In some situations I want to use the Liveview display of my Canon EOS 1100D (USA: Rebel T3, Japan: Kiss X50) and not the viewfinder. But the display switches automatically to viewfinder after some seconds. How to turn this automatic switching off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not that the display switches to viewfinder after some seconds, it is that the camera goes to sleep mode.

So you need to go to `Menu`, then look for the `Auto Power off` option, and choose the timeout value. You can switch it off entirely, which means that your camera would never go into sleep mode, you'd have to manually hit the `OFF` switch to switch the camera off.